# How to have a custom upload button in gwt multiuploader

Tags: gwtupload

I am having a hard time in changing the UI of GWT Multiuploader. Currently it shows a tiny "Choose Files" button [multiuploader's default choose file button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFLk9.png) by clicking on which a new window opens to upload a local file. My requirement is that i would like to replace "Choose Files" button with my own custom Label/Image something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqEKG.png). Also i would like to disable the progress bar of multiuploader. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to use a custom library like https://github.com/jiakuan/gwt-uploader.